# how to get a mask that only contains the inside of a bowl

Tags: node-editor, shaders, procedural, masking

I am trying to texture a bowl (procedurally) and I want a part of a texture to only work on the inside walls of the bowl and vise versa I tried using the back facing option in the geometry node but that seems to work in opposite directions of the normals (I think) whereas in this bowl I want the texture to be on the same side of the surface just not on the outside walls of the mesh.

basically, I want the circular white color only on the inside walls and not on the outside.

[image][image]

Comment: Is using weight paint a viable option? Is much easier to separate the two surfaces at the mesh level. If you cannot, you can use the normal vector to mask out the pieces: Z pointing up is inside, Z pointing down is the outside. Did you tried that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Backfacing* is nearly there .. it's just that the viewing-point the surface is backfacing *to* is the currently evaluated incoming ray, (to all important intents and purposes, from the camera)

We just have to create our own viewing-point, somewhere in the object-space of the bowl, and return to what extent the normal of the surface (also in object-space) is front-facing to *that*.

[image]

.. which is done by taking the dot-product of the normal of the surface, and the unit vector from the shading-point to our custom viewing-point. (The viewing-point is the vector we entered in the *Vector Math > Subtract* node.)

[image]

This example assumes the bowl's object-origin is somewhere on its central axis, and the bowl is 'up' in Z. By adjusting the viewing-point, and the threshold angle of acceptance in the *Greater Than* node, we can get quite fine adjustment: on the left, including the rim of the bowl, in the middle, excluding it.

The pair on the right show how the resulting mask can be used to determine whether or not the color of the surface is modulated by a noise texture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks exactly what i needed

Answer (score 5):

### True normal channel

Given a similar face distribution, you can spot a difference between the normal of the faces on the concave side and the ones on the convex side.

[image]

Just sort them with a math node:

[image]

And exclude the ones who are pointing straight up if you want to get rid of the border.

[image]

Obiuvsly this trick works only for a simple vase like the one you posted, for any other model I would use vertex paint:

[image]

Comment: _True Normal_ from the _Geometry_ node returns the face-normal, before smoothing, in World space .. so the mask is faceted, and as soon as you rotate your bowl, it will slip?

Comment: Yep, sorry, I forgot about the possibililty of this being animated. I'll correct and suggest to use the normal output from texture coordinates node, which "doesn't slip".

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to replicate this method inside geometry nodes but somehow the math and compare nodes have diferent outputs to their equivalents in shading. How could this be done in GN?

Comment: @JuanManuelLynch I would go for something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Zb3.png using the compare node set to "equal", angle 0° and pup up the epsilon till you are satisfied. Let me know if it works for your case.