# How to procedurally identify the Fac of the inside and outside of an object? [EEVEE]

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Here is my question:

As you can see, I have a bowl here with noise material applied to it. The problem is, I only expected the bowl to get noise applied from the inside of the bowl instead of also having the outside to be affected, I want the outside of it to be pure red instead of having yellow scratches like the inside. As far as I know, Blender only let you procedurally identify the Fac of X,Y,Z axis of an object but not the ''depth'' of it. So my question is: Is identifying the ''depth'' of an object possible? If it is, how so? I have also added the Blender file so anyone can access to it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

File: https://blend-exchange.com/b/5kv5GVRx

[image]

Comment: I've corrected the answer I gave to this very question, a while ago. You can find the revision [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201633/35559). On the specific question of 'depth' as in the number of surfaces passed by a ray ... I don't think that's possible with opaque objects, or without jiggery-pokery like OSL.

Comment: Thank you very much!